# Curious on what this function is doing

Tags: java, function, return, invariants

Can someone tell me what is this function doing? I just know that it returns the sum of x + y, but I want to know why. Thanks

```
    public static int f(int x, int y){
    while( y > 0){
        x = x + 1;
        y = y - 1;
    }
    return x;
}
```

Comment: Step through it step by step and put some effort in researching things the next time you have a question.

Comment: if `y <= 0` it just returns `x`, not sum of x + y

Comment: this function add 1 y times to x. So it is returning x+y

Comment: Why is `1 + 1` equal to `2`? [Peano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#Addition) may help you understand.

Comment: Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 3):

There are two cases:

**First case:** *y <= 0*
Because the while loop is false, it just returns **x** ("it skips the part")

**Second case:** *y > 0*
Because the while loop is true, it returns **x + y** *(x + number of iterations)*

The number of iterations is **the value of y** because with every iteration, y will be **decreased** by 1 until **y = 0**.

Answer (score 0):

The loop starts at the value of y, and decrements it on each iteration, stopping when y gets to zero.

For each of these iterations, 1 is added to x. Therefore, for 'unit' of y, a 'unit' is added to x.

**Edit** As noted in the comments, the function will *not* return the sum of the two numbers if `y` is less then zero, since the loop will not execute at all.

Comment: You're assuming that `y` begins with a value greater than zero. As Dmitry Bychenko points out in his comment, if `y` begins with a value of zero or less than zero then nothing is added to `x` and the original value of `x` is returned.

Answer (score -1):

Addition can be viewed as a series of increments. That's what this function does. It increments `x` `y` times and returns the result which is `x + y`. It is assumed that `y` is a natural number.

Comment: Could anyone explain the downvotes and the delete request? I don't get it.

Comment: I don't know, I think your answer is also useful. I gave you +1

Comment: I downvoted because, as other comments and answers have explained, the method does not always return `x + y`, so to state that it returns this is incorrect. If you get downvotes then delete or modify your answer to address any problems like this. (Of course, if you check an answer carefully and decide it's fine as it is then you should just ignore the downvotes.)

Comment: @Bobulous: "...modify your answer to address any problems like this." But that's what I did.

Comment: It still doesn't read right to me. The method does not assume that `y` is greater than zero, it performs an explicit check to determine whether or not it is greater than zero.